# TinyMCE 4.7.11 - Enable hidden WordPress core plugins? (referencing a wp-includes from plugin.php)

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

I need a color picker for the visual editor (don't ask, not my idea).

I thought the TinyMCE colorpicker plugin was removed in WordPress 3.9.

However, I do see `site/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/colorpicker/plugin.min.js`

Am I right to think colorpicker is still supported and just disabled?

If yes, how do I enable it from within `site/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/plugin.php`?

I was hoping just adding the button would work.

```
function smart_grid_tinymce_add_buttons( $buttons ) {   
    $buttons[] = 'colorpicker';

    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'smart_grid_tinymce_add_buttons' );
```

But nope. So I think this means I need to somehow reference the `wp-includes` file, but I don't know how.

I'm a complete newb and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right to think colorpicker is still supported and just disabled?

Yes, **it is still supported**; however, **it's not disabled**, and it's actually loaded by default *by WordPress*, because the [`textcolor` plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/textcolor/) (which is also loaded by default *by WordPress*) *depends on* the [`colorpicker` plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/colorpicker/).

> I was hoping just adding the button would work.

No, because although the *plugin* exists, it does *not* add any *button* to the TinyMCE editor.

### So, create the button manually using the `addButton()` command.

Here's how I did it using a custom TinyMCE plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('mycolorpicker', function(editor) {
  var default_color = '#fffff',
    _current_color;

  // Callback when a color is picked.
  function onColorPicked(color) {
    alert('You picked ' + color);
    _current_color = color; // save it
  }

  editor.addButton('mycolorpicker', {
    text: 'Color Picker',
    icon: false,
    tooltip: 'Pick a color..',
    onclick: function() {
      var cp = editor.settings.color_picker_callback;
      if (cp) {
        // Opens the Color Picker.
        cp(onColorPicked, _current_color || default_color);
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    getMetadata: function () {
      return  {
        name: 'My Color Picker',
        url: 'http://example.com'
      };
    }
  };
});
```

So you can save that to, for example, `mycolorpicker.js` in your plugin's "js" folder or a similar "assets" folder.

And then, load the *plugin* (as an *external* TinyMCE plugin) via the `mce_external_plugins` filter:

```
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', function( $plugins ){
    $plugins['mycolorpicker'] = 'path/to/mycolorpicker.js';

    return $plugins;
} );
```

Finally, add the *button* (`mycolorpicker` in the above example plugin) via the `mce_buttons` filter. (Or use `mce_buttons_2` to add the button to the *second* toolbar row, which by default, contains the "Text color" button)

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', function( $buttons ){
    $buttons[] = 'mycolorpicker';

    return $buttons;
} );
```

Try a demo of the plugin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djZjMo

---

Resources (TinyMCE):

- TinyMCE's [`textcolor`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/textcolor/) and [`colorpicker`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/colorpicker/) plugins
- [Create a Custom Toolbar Button](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-custom-button/) using [`addButton()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#addbutton)
- [Create a Plugin for TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/)

Comment: Sally CJ to the rescue again - Thank you so much for the fast and complete answer - you rock!